# Accessing to the button of the Window taskbar (Ie Running applications) with pywinauto

Tags: windows, taskbar, pywinauto

I would like to access to buttons that are in window taskbar (like IE, Explorer, ...). I need the automationId of some button.

If I used Visual UI Automation tool, I see that the buttons are in the toolbar "Running Applications" (Class MSTaskListWClass).

(Sorry, I can't post a picture beacause this is my first post)

I try :

```
>>> taskbar.RunningApplications
<pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification object at 0x02F5C830>
>>> taskbar.RunningApplications.children()
[]
```

=> I don't understand, because the running applications taskbar is not empty (at least the current cmd application)

I try also:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto import Desktop
import pywinauto 
import re as regex

def dump(o):
    s = ("name %s ClassName %s Hdler %s" % (o.name.encode('utf-8'),o.class_name.encode('utf-8'),hex(o.handle)))
    return s 

# Point d'entree l 1
l1 = pywinauto.findwindows.find_elements(class_name_re = 'Shell_TrayWnd')
print("Lg %d - %s" % (len(l1),dump(l1[0])))   

l2 = pywinauto.findwindows.find_elements(class_name_re = 'ReBarWindow32')
print l2    

shell_TrayWnd = l1[0]
l3 =  shell_TrayWnd.children()  
for i in range(len(l3)): 
   if regex.search('MSTaskSwWClass',l3[i].class_name):
      print ("Fuundl3[%2d] %s" % (i, dump(l3[i]))) 
      listButton = l3[i].children()[0]

print("listButton  %s" % (dump(listButton))) 
print listButton.children()
```

This is the sample problem : the list of running applications seems to be empty.

So my questions are :

- Bad usage of pywauto ?
- Are the buttons children of the MSTaskListWClass GUi element ? The Visual UI Automation tool gives 0x00 as Handler for each buttons. This is strange
- Bug in pywinauto ? The problem seems to be in pywinauto 0.61 or 0.65
- This is not possible to this with pywinauto ?
- If I succeed to access to running application button, is it possible to read the AutomationId field ?

Thanks for ideas or any pointers,
PHLinux

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. It’s considered polite on StackOverflow and it motivates to answer your next questions.

Answer (score 0):

`find_elements` is a low level function not recommended for direct usage (I don't mention it in the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)). This code is working for me:

```
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title='Taskbar') # backend is important!!!
#app.Taskbar.dump_tree() # was needed for next step, just copied child_window spec from here

running_apps = app.Taskbar.child_window(title="Running applications", control_type="ToolBar")
print([w.window_text() for w in running_apps.children()])
# running_apps.dump_tree() # another debug print for auto_id properties advice
```